# Find the recent downloaded repo from GitLab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gitlab

I'm downloading my code from my private repo. When the download is finished using the following command :

```
wget -O project.tar.gz https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1/repository/archive?private_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I end up with an archive :

```
project.tar.gz
```

Which I extract

```
tar -zxf project.tar.gz
```

And it gives me the following folder :

```
project-master-97fe635dc27fb89bd16e3448bf6915420
```

But I have an older downloaded folder in the same path, so I have :

```
folder
│
└─── project-master-97fe635dc27fb89bd16e3448bf6915420
|
└─── project-master-28ba625ab48ac14bd25c7119aa9511271
```

I have the following command to find the folder :

```
find /path/ -name "project-master-*"
```

But its output me 2 results :

```
/path/project-master-97fe635dc27fb89bd16e3448bf6915420
/path/project-master-28ba625ab48ac14bd25c7119aa9511271
```

I would like to output only the most recent repo version :

```
/path/project-master-97fe635dc27fb89bd16e3448bf6915420
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use find for this. You should use `ls` for sorting by modification time and `head` to pick the newest one:

```
$ ls -dt /path/project-master-* | head -1
```

`ls -dt` lists directories (not their content), and sorts them by modification time.

Solution works for directories without spaces and/or other special characters.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)